# Zipping an ExcelPackage in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have created an excel document in code and I'm trying to zip the file using ZipArchive. I was attempting to do this by using BinaryReader/Writers but the the stream that I tried to make doesn't seem to contain anything. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
Using zip As ZipArchive = New ZipArchive(MemoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, True)
            Dim excelFile As ZipArchiveEntry = zip.CreateEntry("QueryExportTest.xlsx")
            Using writer As BinaryWriter = New BinaryWriter(excelFile.Open())
                Dim excelReader As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(excel.Stream())

                While excelReader.PeekChar() <> -1
                    writer.Write(excelReader.ReadBoolean)
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
```

excel was defined earlier with `Dim excel As New ExcelPackage()`